# Cannot save value in Arabic from in java

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have the below code, I want to save the below Arabic value in the database

```
public String approveAction() {

        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();

        ADFUtils.findOperation("CreateInsert1").execute();

        ADFUtils.setBoundAttributeValue( "Announcment", "تمت الموافقة على الطلب الخاص بـ");

        // ADFUtils.setBoundAttributeValue( "RqStatus", "Approved");

         ADFUtils.findOperation("Commit").execute();

         ADFUtils.findOperation("Execute").execute();


    return null;

    }
```

But in the database it is displayed as below:

E?E C???C??E ??? C???E C?IC? EU

Noting that Arabic is saved normally when inserting in the database directly, or from the fields of my screen, the problem occurs only in the Java code.
Please advise what is the problem.

Comment: the 'problem' is using the wrong encoding.

Comment: Make sure that your database encoding is utf-8

Comment: make sure that your database schema is created with utf-8, make sure that jvm runs with utf-8 encoding , make sure that you set the encoding on the database connection URL

Comment: Indeed, the problem is from the encoding,  I change it from project properties>compiler>character encoding and choose utf8 or default, both worked successfully .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your application encoding in web.xml file

```html
<init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

if not solve please try to convert encoding in java file.